# Требуется имя метода C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку, ошибка в rnd.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    dataBase.RowCount = 20;
    dataBase.ColumnCount = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                dataBase[i, j].Value = "Англия";
            }
            if(i==1)
            {
                dataBase[i, j].Value = rnd(1,10);
            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                dataBase[i, j].Value = rnd(1,10) ;
            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                dataBase[i, j].Value = rnd(1, 10);
            }
            if (i == 4)
            {
                dataBase[i, j].Value = rnd(1, 10);
            }
            if (i == 5)
            {
                dataBase[i, j].Value = rnd(1, 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `rnd.Next(1,10);` Код, конечно, сюрреалистичный.

Comment: Cпасибо, тупанул!)

Comment: почитайте про switch,пригодится

Comment: @TEA спасибо за совет, но я знаю как использовать switch, просто задание заключалось в использовании if

Comment: @Alex, а вы уверены в том, что знаете как работает if? кто мешал написать `if (i == 0)
            {
                dataBase[i, j].Value = "Англия";
            }else
            {
                dataBase[i, j].Value = rnd.Next(1,10);
            }`